# Why is the "returning reference to temporary object" compiler warning not triggered?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pass-by-reference, msvc12

Consider this simple code:

```
struct Container {
    struct Item {};

    Item operator[](size_t /*index*/) const {
        return Item();
    }

    const Item& f() const {
        return operator[](0);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Container c;
    const Container::Item& item = *c.begin();

    return 0;
}
```

It has a bug, and I'm surprised it only took me about 30 minutes to notice: `iterator::operator*()` returns a reference to temporary object. Usually it throws a warning. Why not in this case?

MSVC 2013 (v120 toolset), compiled with `/W4`.

P. S. This is [C4172](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0ws2xs1.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), a level 1 warning.

Comment: FWIW, the expected "warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary" is what I'm getting with http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/.

Comment: This may be a bug.  MSVS 2015 issues *warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary*

Comment: ah, is it because you aren't returning a temporary object? you're storing a reference to the container, so if that container is destructed you'd get a segfault? I don't see how that object is temporary in the scope of the operator if it's parameter container is defined edit:ah right because container operator returns the temporary...sorry for all of my noise

Comment: @NathanOliver: then perhaps of note is that I've got VS 2013 Update 4, and the latest is Update 5. Wonder if it's fixed there. I can't update for technical reasons.

Comment: @kirinthos: look closely at *what* `operator*` *returns*. It's a clear bug.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe you are returning a reference, but it is not temporary

Comment: @vu1p3n0x: I'm returning a reference **to** temporary. The reference becomes invalid as soon as `operator*` returns.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x `_container[_idx]` generates a temporary.  Trying to return that by reference is not going to end well.

Comment: Wild guess here, but some compilers don't generate warnings on optimized-out code. Item is empty and never meaningfully used; it might be stripping it, at least in the given example.

Comment: @WilliamKappler: nope. 1. it's debug build; 2. it is merely a minimal example of a live bug from a live program that I spent half a live hour debugging :)

Comment: Is it possible that the temporary is getting optimized out via RVO or similar, resulting in code that is effectively equivilent to `const Container::Item& item = Container::Item();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is a bug in Visual Studio, you can find it was reported for VS 2012 and it appears it was still present in 2013:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/776530/warning-c4172-not-emitted

Above link might be a duplicate of some other, the example from this bug report looks quite the same as your sample code:

```
// main.cpp

struct A
{
};


struct B
{    
    A a() const {return A();}
};

struct C
{
    A const& a() const
    {
        return B().a();
    }
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good old Microsoft *Status : Closed  as Won't Fix  Won't Fix*

Comment: This is not a bug but considered by MS as a feature, anyway it was added intentianally

Comment: Well since vs2015 this feautre was removed,you can find here similar report with detailed explanation why its bad: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1425276/false-positive-error-c4172-returning-address-of-local-variable-or-temporary